# Cosa significa "traversare le linee"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*, di Erri De Luca, ho letto queste parole che fanno riferimento a sua madre quando lui era bambino:

> Dritta nella schiena, estranea al viavai, questa era la tua camminata per la strada. Allora ero d'accordo con la tua fermezza. Tenevi a bada il popolo rischioso e lo solcavi come si **traversano le linee**.

Ricercando su Google "traversare le linee" ho visto che si tratta di un'espressione abbastanza usata, ma non sono riuscita a trovarne il significato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Attraversare le linee*** è una espressione militare che indica l'atto di oltrepassare il fronte di combattimento e introdursi in terra nemica, superando in qualche modo la difesa avversaria, come definito nel Vocabolario Treccani alla voce *linea* al punto 3.c  [*attraversare le l. nemiche*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/linea/). Si può fare in modo palese, ad esempio con un salvacondotto, di nascosto oppure con un sotterfugio; si tratta comunque di una azione pericolosa e difficile.

La madre di Erri de Luca considerava la gente per la strada un po' come dei nemici, persone ostili da tenere a bada. Insomma non era un tipo affabile e socievole, pronto a fare amicizia con tutti; piuttosto si sentiva minacciata e pensava a difendersi.

Answer (score 0):

Secondo me qui nell'accezione *"Mettere, disporre, o anche stendere per traverso"* (vedi [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/traversare/)); e significa che la camminata della madre era in grado di "fendere" la folla delle altre persone che camminavano per la strada "di traverso" ovvero non nello stesso del moto di queste persone, ma come per esempio due linee tracciate in modo perpendicolare.